# How to get all values kendo calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/calendar/selection

I used calendar from above url.

I can not get values by dragging to choose values. I tried following code.

http://jsfiddle.net/j0qpdox3/

In this fiddle you can see the first column values are displayed start date field and last column values are displayed the end date.

For example drag the date 9 to 15.

Other values are not working. Ex (10 to 14).

```
var cal = $("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
  selectable: "multiple",
  change: function() {

    $(".k-state-selected").each(function(){
  var textVal = $('.k-state-selected:first-child a').attr("data-value");
  var textVal1 = $('.k-state-selected:last-child a').attr("data-value");

          $("#startdate").val(textVal);
         $("#enddate").val(textVal1);


  });


  }
});
```

ow can i get the first child and last child values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you have enabled `selectable: "multiple"` you can use `selectDates()` of kendo ui, which will return the `array` of selected dates.

try the following.

```
var cal = $("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
    selectable: "multiple",
    change: function() {
        //var textVal = this.value();
        var seldataes = this.selectDates(); // newly added
        var textVal = kendo.toString(new Date(seldataes[0]), "yyyy/MM/dd"); // newly added
        var textVal1 = kendo.toString(new Date(seldataes[seldataes.length - 1]), "yyyy/MM/dd"); // newly added
        console.log(textVal);
        $("#startdate").val(textVal);
        $("#enddate").val(textVal1);


    }
});
```

hope this helps.

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/q4c3j8bp/)